# Do something when a foreach data-binding is completed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my form a list is "filled" by knockout. Here's the `ul` code:

```html
<ul class="sortable ui-widget-content" data-bind="foreach: menus">
   <li>
      <a href="#" data-bind="attr: { title: name }, click: $parent.navigate">
         <i data-bind="attr: { class: iconClass }"></i>
             <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And it works just fine. What I need now is that when the `foreach` is done, run a piece of code. Any ideas on how to implement that?

Comment: Curious: *why* do you (think you) need this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Knockout Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html): (look at `afterRender`, note 7)

> If you need to run some further custom logic on the generated DOM
>   elements, you can use any of the
>   `afterRender/afterAdd/beforeRemove/beforeMove/afterMove` callbacks

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: myItems, afterAdd: yellowFadeIn }">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ko.applyBindings({
        myItems: ko.observableArray([ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]),
        yellowFadeIn: function(element, index, data) {
            $(element).filter("li")
                      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }, 200)
                      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'white' }, 800);
        },
        addItem: function() { this.myItems.push('New item'); }
    });
</script>
```

Are you looking something like this?

**EDIT:** In this case `afterRender` should be ok

Comment: something like that yes... but the documentation says that "Add" happens everytime a new element enters... I was hoping for a event like "<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: myItems, **afterDone**: yellowFadeIn }">
"

Comment: "Add" is used as an example in documentation, but you can use "afterRender". I've edited my answer